# Alter configurable product programmatically

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product

I need to add additional attribute to a configurable product (**Super attribute**).
As seen in

> Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Variations\Config\Matrix

Data is generated based on input and send to post parameter.
Is there a possibility to do it programmatically to alter super attributes?

Like this for example there is a configurable product with super attributes size, color. But the need is to add another attribute width and do it in bulk using migration script (**with possibility to alter generated product matrix before building it**).